# How to access parameters in resolving method passed in resolve helper

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, data-binding

Resolving Game class and passing two parameters.

```
resolve(Game::class,['param1'=>'hello','param2'=>'world']);
```

Therefore, service container fires an event while resolving a game class object.

```
$this->app->resolving(Game::class, function (){
            echo "<script>alert('hello')</script>";
        });
```

In the above code I am showing an alert. How can I access **param1** and **param2**? In [Container Event](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#container-events) how **$app** and **$api** or the function is used? Could not find proper example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP API Reflection allows you to get some informations about a class constructor, such as parameters name, type, etc... but it does not allow to know the arguments passed to an instance of this class. Though, you could easily retrieve them from `resolving` method with this way

```php
<?php

class Game
{
    protected $param1;

    protected $param2;

    public function __construct($param1, $param2)
    {
        $this->param1 = $param1;
        $this->param2 = $param2;
    }

    public function getParam1()
    {
        return $this->param1;
    }

    public function getParam2()
    {
        return $this->param2;
    }
}
```

```php
$this->app->resolving(Game::class, function (Game $game, $app){
    $param1 = $game->getParam1();
    $param2 = $game->getParam2();
});
```

Comment: thank you. can you suggest any good tutorial for contextual binding?

Comment: @Chakma https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/bd857d9b0ac895df7604dd2e63b23afe